# Price differences in Ruby rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, matrix

I am wondering what best practice is for RubyRails to calculate price differences.

Lets say I have a table with price updates for package combo's.

Each package combo exists out: store_id, product_id, product_id

Each price update has one product-combo.

Now I want to calculate each package combo that exists in every store. So... example:

```
**Table Package deals**
id 1, Store A,  Flightticket 2, Busticket 3   *
id 2, Store B, Flightticket 2, Busticket 3    *
id 3, Store A, Flightticket 1, Busticket 2
id 4, Store B, Flightticket 3, Busticket 1
id 5, Store C, Flightticket 2, Busticket 3    *

**Table Price updates**
id 1, package deal 1, EUR 10
id 2, package deal 2, EUR 12
id 3, package deal 5, EUR 15
```

So the result that I want here is a dataset with the price difference of each store.. Something like:

```
            Store A    Store B     Store C
                10       12          15
Store A  10    xxx       -2          -5         
Store B  12      2      xxx          -3  
Store C  15      5        3         xxx
+ the price difference %
```

I have no clue where to start Im just learning Ruby :D

Comment: You want a dataset with the results, or a browser view with the results?

Comment: dataset.. The rest is for later :D

Comment: I want to trigger an email. (for example) event when for example a big price difference occurs.. so thats why I need the comparison data

Comment: If you've just started learning Ruby and Rails, you really should go through a tutorial and get a good book (there are a few) before you tackle a task like this. Asking it as a question here is going to be too broad since it amounts to giving you a language tutorial, not just addressing a specific question.

Comment: I did and then I got to this part.. All the prices are loading with api's already. data is stored in each model. Im just asking for best practice. Not asking you to code for me